# Content not displaying while using CSS vh units and Percentages

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When using CSS `vh` and percentages to define the height for an element ( e.g. div ), will the element stretch if the content overflow the element.

In my pen, I am trying to fill in content for the bottom div ( which has a id of contact ). However once the content overflow, the div does not resize. 
[my pen](https://codepen.io/MrFahrenheit/pen/ybrYrZ)

Comment: You can set `min-height` that for `height`

Comment: Your Right, however shouldn't the content still show. Why is there just a white space for where the content should be

Comment: Where You are mention element in your pen

Comment: Your way of hiding and showing elements is not correct. You need `display:none` and `display:block` istead of changing elements `height` from `0%` to `100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height 25% is ok, just the `font-size: 30px` does not fit that much of content, so I added `overflow:hidden` so you can see it is because the text content. change the font-size should help.

```
  .section-style {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```js
function openNav() {

  document.getElementById("mysidenav").style.height = "100%";
  document.getElementById("window-top").style.height = "0%";


}

function closeNav() {

  document.getElementById("mysidenav").style.height = "0%";
  document.getElementById("window-top").style.height = "100%";


}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
    height: 25%;
  }
  .sidenav {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 0%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  #nav-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .pages-box {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid white;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 35%;
  }
  .pages {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #green {
    background-color: #195407;
  }
  #brown {
    background-color: #542407;
  }
  #purple {
    background-color: #540719;
  }
  #blue {
    background-color: #072b54;
  }
  .btn-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
  }
  .closebtn {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 4em;
    background-color: #542407;
    border: none;
  }
  #dropbtn {
    height: 40%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #542407;
    border: none;
  }
  #window-top {
    height: 100%;
    transition: 2s;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  #style-title {
    display: flex;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #195407;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  #title {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  #style-signature {
    display: flex;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: #072b54;
  }
  #signature {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    font-family: AlexBrush;
  }
  .section-style {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #facts {
    background-color: #195407;
  }
  #traits {
    background-color: #072b54;
  }
  #contact {
    background-color: #540719;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MainStyle.css">
  <script src="action.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title> Site of Demetrius Tuggle </title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <nav id="mysidenav" class="sidenav">
      <ul id="nav-box">

        <li class="pages-box" id="green"><a href="#" class="pages"> Home </a></li>
        <li class="pages-box" id="brown"><a href="#" class="pages"> Experience </a></li>
        <li class="pages-box" id="purple"><a href="#" class="pages"> Aspirations </a></li>
        <li class="pages-box" id="blue"><a href="#" class="pages"> Contact Me </a></li>
        <li class="btn-box"><button class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&#735;</button></li>


      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="window-top">
      <div id="style-title">

        <h1 id="title">
          Demetrius Tuggle
        </h1>

      </div>

      <div id="style-signature">

        <div id="signature"> Curosity &#43; Time </div>

      </div>
      <button id="dropbtn" onclick="openNav ()"> &#9776; </button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="section-style" id="facts">


  </section>


  <section class="section-style" id="traits">

  </section>


  <section class="section-style" id="contact">
    Why is the rest of this sentence not appearing. Shouldn't this div and everything else in this document resize to fit the rest of this sentence. Is the problem with using percentages, vh units or both.
  </section>

</body>
```